# .htaccess file's puzzling action (code inside)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this CMS set up in a folder called `localhost:5999/madison/`

The `.htaccess` file (code below) is in the same folder `localhost:5999/madison/`

If, in a browser, I go to `localhost:5999/madison/` or to `localhost:5999/madison/index.php` or to `localhost:5999/madison/xyz` where xyz is anything not containing forward slashes, it redirects me to the following file: `localhost:5999/madison/inc/views/view-404.php`

My question is: Why?

**.htaccess code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
ExpiresActive On

#Expire Header
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "now plus 7 days"
</FilesMatch>

ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/html "now plus 7 days"
ExpiresDefault "now plus 7 days"

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css

RewriteRule ^(assets|inc) - [L]

RewriteRule ^admin[/]?$                         admin/index 

RewriteRule ^admin/edit/(.*)$                   index.php?type=admin&action=edit&page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$                        index.php?type=admin&action=view&page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^login$                             index.php?action=view&type=login&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^forgot-password$                   index.php?action=view&type=forgot-password&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^edit/user(/)?$                     index.php?action=edit&type=user&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^signup(/)?$                        index.php?action=edit&type=user&id=0&%1  [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)(/)?                  index.php?action=view&type=note&user=$1&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(suggestion|comment)/([0-9]+)(/)?  index.php?action=view&type=note&page=open&note_type=$1&note=$2&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]+)/(suggestion|comment)/([0-9]+)(/)?    index.php?action=view&type=note&page=$1&note_type=$2&note=$3&%1 [L]

#Catch All Pages
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]+)(/)?          index.php?action=view&type=page&page=$1&%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises because you are hosting the CMS in a sub-folder `localhost:5999/madison/` (without changes to the [configuration file](https://github.com/opengovfoundation/the-madison-project/blob/master/inc/config.php)) and not directly in `localhost:5999/`

To solve the issue, make the following changes to `config.php` in `/madison/inc/` directory:

**`config.php`**

```
/**
 *  Server Definitions
 */
define('SERVER_ABS', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('SERVER_URL', 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

To:

```
/**
 *  Server Definitions
 */
define('SERVER_ABS', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/madison');
define('SERVER_URL', 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/madison');
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be borne out for some custom 404 handler outside your current .htaccess.

Try adding these lines on top of your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /madison/
```

And keep your last rule as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?action=view&type=page&page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then test this in a new browser to avoid old caches.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, "RewriteBase /madison/" causes a 500 error.

Comment: Good question. First I pasted in everything and got that error. After that I kept removing parts one by one till only that line was left and got that error. Here's something from the error.log: "[Mon Nov 03 12:14:35.604466 2014] [core:alert] [pid 4670] [client ::1:50074] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/madison/.htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context"

Comment: That means you have some typo as `RewriteBase /madison/` has exact one argument after `RewriteBase`. Are you sure you copy pasted it exactly? What editor are you using for this editing?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had added a #comment after that statement, and it was being counted as a second argument. I removed it, and don't get the 500 error any more. Am going to try out the other lines now.